# How to center this navigation bar?

Tags: css, navigation

This site is using a theme which I thought had a centered navigation bar... turns out it doesn't.

http://richdales.com/

I can override/change any CSS necessary, but I'm not sure what to look for.

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What have you already tried?  The nav as-is uses float: left; to align the links horizontally.  Change this to display: inline-block; instead.  That will keep them horizontally aligned but it will do it in a way that you can then add text-align: center; to the UL element to center them.

Answer (score 2):

in you css :

```
nav#main-nav.full .shell > ul{
    text-align: center;
}

nav#main-nav.full .shell > ul > li{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And for the nav#main-nav.full .shell > ul > li, remove the float:left; and it's gonna work :).

Answer (score 0):

Set nav#main-nav.full .shell > ul to

```
display:inline-block; width:100%; text-align:center;
```

Remove float:left from nav#main-nav.full .shell > ul > li and set them to

```
display:inline;
```

Finally remove display:block from nav#main-nav.full .shell > ul > li > a

That way the li items will sit inline and centred as intended.